# Activity finishes too quickly when loading for the first time at first launch

Tags: android, android-activity, preferenceactivity

Am using this code to make an `Activity` load only when the app is launched for the first time but am having an issue, the `Activity` that is supposes to launch for the first time is a `WebView`, and while the `WebView` is loading the `Activity` finishes too quickly. This is the code am using to make the `Activity` load for the first time.

```
count = readSharedPreferenceInt("cntSP","cntKey");
if(count==0){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, TemporaryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    count++;
    writeSharedPreference(count,"cntSP","cntKey");
}

//Read from Shared Preferance
public int readSharedPreferenceInt(String spName,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(spName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return tempInt = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
}     

//write shared preferences in integer
public void writeSharedPreference(int ammount,String spName,String key ){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(spName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt(key, ammount);
    editor.commit();
}
```

This is the code for the activity that loads for the first time

```
public class Reg_Status extends AppCompatActivity {
 Context a;
 private ProgressBar pBar;

/* renamed from: com.partners.app.Confmap.1 */
class C01561 extends WebViewClient {
    C01561() {
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Reg_Status.this.pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Reg_Status.this.pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        view.loadUrl(Config.URL_INTERNET_ERROR);
        Reg_Status.this.pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }
}



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_reg_status);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pBar);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wView_reg);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new C01561());
    webView.loadUrl(Config.URL_REG);


}
```

Comment: More interesting would be the code where you finish the `TemporaryActivity`. It does not go away from alone.

Comment: I think you are doing it inside onCreate() of the first Activity and it appears as the first Activity is not visible at all.

Comment: @Henry please find edited code for activity that is suppose to load at first launch

Comment: @vidulaJ you are right am doing it inside the onCreate. what am i suppose to do then?

Comment: Are you waiting for any event to happen before going to the second Activity? If so, you got to wait and I think you got to implement or create a callback method for that.

Comment: @vidulaJ, yes an event is suppose to happen, its a webview that is suppose to finish loading so the user can perform an operation first on this webview. am a rookie how can I implement or create a callback. can you answer with a code snippet so I can try and accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. You have this method, `onPageFinished()`, implemented and do that snippet you are doing it inside `onCreate()` inside that method.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //You code, which you had put inside onCreate() should go here.
}
```

**EDIT**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TemporaryActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
...
```

**NEW EDIT**

```
public class C01561 extends WebViewClient {
    private Context context;
    C01561(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Reg_Status.this.pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TemporaryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And when you create an instance of `WebViewClient` make sure to pass the `MainActivity` context.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new C01561(MainActivity.this));
```

Comment: should I still do this in onCreate?

Comment: Nope. You have this class WebViewClient and inside it there is an implemented method, onPageFinished(), and do it inside this method.

Comment: how do I now set the this intent :- Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, TemporaryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent); MainActivity.this shows an error

Comment: MainActiivty is not an enclosing class, the Intent was from MainActivity to Temporary activity, the temporary activity which is the second activity is what has the onPageFinished, and this is the activity that I want to show first

Comment: See the EDIT in the original answer. Ah yes. Got the error. You got to pass a Context variable via the constructor of the WebViewClient class and then start the Activity. See the NEW EDIT.

Comment: I have implemented this how do I now make this TemporaryActivity show first after my splash screen since it not my MainActivity

Comment: Put this snippet wherever you load your WebView then.

Answer (score 1):

Create one Handler to delay the start of the Second Activity.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, TemporaryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }, TIME_OUT);
```

Now, call this handler in your if condition and set `TIME_OUT` accordingly.

Comment: since I need the the webview to finish loading which can be different time based on the speed of the users internet I do I make it know when the webview finish loading completely first

Comment: In that case you can do it in `onPageFinished` of WebViewClient

Comment: am actually implementing this code in my MainActivity, does that mean I will now implement this in onPageFinished which is in the activity that suppose to show first at first launch, if so can you edit it using my code then.tnks